# Запись текстовой строки по нужному индексу в файл на языке Си?

Tags: c, строки, файлы

Здравствуйте. Интересует вопрос, как можно записать в файл строку, не трогая остальные строки по нужному индексу.

Например, у меня 3 строки в файле:

```
строка 1
строка 2
строка 3
```

Мне нужно заменить строку 2 на `ййййй`:

```
строка 1
ййййй
строка 3
```

То что получается у меня, это постоянная перезапись всего файла с помощью `fprintf()`. Но так не пойдет, у меня там 100 000 записей. Также нужно вставлять строки небольшими блоками (примерно по 60 строк).

Заранее всем спасибо. Использовать можно только функции языка Си.

Comment: А файл открыт на добавление? (В fopen какой режим выбран) Это чтобы он не перезаписывал файл. А по файлу можно ходить через функцию fseek. Возможно я не до конца вас понял. **Обновление** Fseek умеет переводить курсор внутри файла, там атрибут fsetpos есть он за это отвечает. Будете когда 100000 строк достиг ставить курсор в начало файла **SEEK_SET**. Почитайте.

Comment: c или c++ тоже можно?

Comment: нет только Си возможно .

Comment: Понятно. В двух словах я уже ответил и расширенные ответы уже даны. Ишите компромис - или все 100000 строк в память поместяться, или ещё один вспомогательный файл. Другого не дано.

Answer (score 8):

Нежозможно заменить блок в середине файла на блок другого размера, при этом не разрушив последующего содержимого файла. Другими словами - не системном уровне обычно невозможно вставить новое и сместить старое содержимое файла. Если `kernel` и `filesystem` поддерживают, то есть очень ограниченная возможность [писать в середине файла](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187211/1321).

Самое оптимальное решение - открыть оригинал для чтения, читать построчно и добавляя/изменяя писать в новый файл, в конце заменив оригинал новым.

Можно конечно попробовать найти место откуда писать, и начинать оттуда переписывать, т.е. `seek()`, `fread()`, `seek()` и `fwrite()`, но весь остаток предыдущего содержимого файла должен быть в памяти, и если `fwrite()` по какой-либо причине не завершится, оригинальный файл будет утерян. Если он дорог как память и надо избежать случая - *батарейка села* - содержимое памяти надо дублировать в `swap` с возможностью `recovery`.

Так что или решение описанное выше, или меняйте формат, или сторонние решения / библиотеки - например Berkeley DB.

Comment: так делаю но писать 100000 строк сильно дорого когда раз в 5 минут меняются только 60

Comment: @Aldmi: А других вариантов нет. Выбранный вами текстовый формат не позволяет модифицировать данные в середине. Меняйте формат.

Comment: ОСь/filesystem может предоставить (очень ограниченную) возможность работать в середине файла даже если это может изменить его размер без переписывания всего файла. Пример: можно [использовать `fallocate()`, чтобы удалить данные из начала файла](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187211/1321)

Comment: @jfs согласен, моё утверждение "совсем невозможно" не совсем верно, скорее  надо было что-то нейтральное - ось обычно  не поддерживает ...

Answer (score 7):

Как вы понимаете, если вставляемая строка не равна по длине той, которую она заменяет - счастья (вставить только ее, не трогая остальные) не получится.

Если вам повезло и она точно такая же по длине - становитесь на нужное место *в том же файле* с помощью функции `fseek` и записываете строку с помощью `fwrite` или той же `fprintf`.

Если не повезло - то надо переписывать данные в другой файл (так проще) с последующим его переименованием. Сами прикиньте, какая морока, если вставляемая строка длиннее, чем та, что была - надо постоянно считывать данные наперед, чтоб не затерлись при перезаписи, и хранить их...

Перезаписывать в другой файл большими блоками просто - выделяете буфер, открываете файлы (исходный и вновь созданный) в бинарном режиме (иначе считать будет трудно), и читаете-пишете блоками с помощью `fread` и `fwrite`. Аккуратно отслеживая, сколько именно надо прочитать до искомой строки, затем новую строку, затем переход с помощью `fseek` за строку, и снова читаете-пишете до конца файла.

Естественно, сначала вам нужно найти, с какой позиции в файле располагается искомая строка.

Если файл **небольшой** и легко размещается в памяти - проще считать его весь в буфер достаточного размера, с помощью `memmove` расчистить место под запись строки, обнулить старый файл и записать заново.

Если эта операция у вас постоянная - *крайне* рекомендую подумать об использовании другого формата файла. Например, при известной максимальной длине строки хранить каждую строку в блоке размера, достаточного для размещения максимальной строки. Вы потеряете на размере файла, но **очень** сэкономите на файловых операциях. Есть и другие варианты, но этот самый простой.

Comment: информация о каждой строке у меня уже хранится в памяти тоесть 10000

Comment: Т.е. вы постоянно держите все строки в памяти? Ну так работайте там, а когда надо - сбрасывайте все в файл. Т.е. выполняйте простое кэширование :) В любом случае, если длины строк до и после замены не равны - переписывать надо все, что в файле после этой строки. Если, конечно, это обычный текстовый файл.

Comment: информация о каждой строке у меня уже хранится в памяти. и мне нужно за раз скинуть все в файл *.csv скидывать построчно 100000 строк если поменялось только 60 это не хорошо. Строки я выровняю по длине и указатель для записи (смешение) тоже могу иметь.

Comment: ОК как быстро скинуть 100000 строк char[0x400]?

Comment: Если эти строки лежат в непрерывном блоке памяти - быстрее `fwrite` ничего не получится. Впрочем, если и по отдельности - то тоже лучше писать каждую строку этой же функцией, а не `fprintf`, которая делает массу лишней работы.

Comment: я работаю на АРМ -ом проце под линуском и тупо начал натыкаться на зависание программы больше чем время ватчдога.

Comment: нет я на каждой итерации цикла по сути вычисляю саму строку. потом ее надо писать. хранить все в памяти очень дорого. в памяти хранится  числовая инфа нужная для вычисления строк.

Comment: Простите, но у меня начинает складываться впечатление, что вам нужно искать какие-то принципиально иные подходы к вашей исходной задаче, а не пытаться просто ускорить запись в файл.

Comment: Ладно как бы вы записывали 100000 строк которые перебираются в цикле и за раз можно записать только 1 строку? я так понял с помощью fwrite?

Comment: @Aldmi  Если плоский файл (csv) не подходит для вашей задачи (не фиксированный формат строки, редактирование в середине), то чтобы не изобретать велосипед, можно использовать базу данных такую как sqlite, которая позволяет не переписывать 100000 строк, если нужно одну обновить.

Comment: База не подходит по ТЗ должно быть именно так. Пусть длинна строки фиксированная. Смотрите ниже мой же ответ на вопрос почему у меня не смешается указатель после fseek ?

Comment: @Aldmi, посмотрите (в линуксе) на man mmap

Answer (score 3):

Первое, что вам нужно сделать, это определить максимальную возможную длину строки, которую вы планируете писать в файл. Затем, представьте файл, как массив строк этой фиксированной длины. И теперь, поскольку длина фиксирована, найти позицию в файле, куда нужно записывать данные, не составит труда. Главное, не забыть пустое место в конце строк, меньших максимальной, забить пробелами, чтобы в файл не записался случайный мусор.

При таком подходе у вас будет оверхед на занимаемое место на диске, но вы получите возможность перезаписывать любую строку в любой момент времени.

Если вас такой оверхед не устраивает, то вам нужно смотреть в сторону БД (SQLite) поскольку руками сделать нормальное изменение произвольных (не фиксированных по длине) строк невозможно. Хотя, в БД тоже будет небольшой оверхед по диску, так что тут надо смотреть на конкретных данных и принципиальной возможности ввести/выбрать фиксированную длину строки.

Answer (score 1):

Если отвечать формально, то - никак.  Если же попытаться понять, что нужно автору на самом деле - то становится ясно, что задача - типовая и решение у неё тоже - типовое.

Первое, что нужно сделать - отвязать физическое расположение строки (записи) в файле от её логического порядка (номера, индекса ...)

В файл физического хранения строк сами строки пишем как попало. Можно даже не писать символы перевода строки. В 99.99% случаев новую строку пишем просто в конец этого файла.

Заводим хэш-таблицу (для лубителей STL - map), в которой ключём будет ЛОГИЧЕСКИЙ номер строки, а значением - струкутра вида:

```
struct Descriptor {
    size_t pisition;
    size_t len;
}
```

Если объём таблицы не слишком велик, то можно её целиком в памяти разместить, в противном случае, проще всего воспользоваться  Berkeley DB для хранения этой таблицы в виде файла.

Т.е., зная ЛОГИЧЕСКИЙ номер строки, Вы считываете её дескриптор из хэш-таблицы, а по нему считываете саму строку из основного файла.

Таким образом, для выбора строки нужно всего два (!) обращения к диску.
Для добавления новой строки нужно записать её в конец основного файла и занести её координаты в хэш. Т.е. тоже два обращения.

С удалением строк из основного файла несколько сложнее получается. Нужно написать специальный сборщик мусора и запускатье его, когда нет загрузки основной системы.

Comment: Ваше предложение на самом деле — смена текстового формата на достаточно сложный. По сути вы изобретаете заново хранение VARCHAR'ов в базе. Боюсь, в рамках данного вопроса это слишком сложное решение.

Comment: **смена текстового формата на достаточно сложный** - сами строки хранятся в том же самом стандартном формате. Добавлен только хэш для номеров (!!!) строк.

Comment: **вы изобретаете заново хранение VARCHAR'ов** - не понял... Причём тут строки переменной длины ?!

Comment: **это слишком сложное решение** - проще Berkeley DB вы ничего не придумаете!. Если Вы хотели сказать, что это решение слишком сложно для УЧЕБНОЙ задачи, то я с Вами соглашусь. Если же задача реальная, а не учебная, то есть только два варианта: либо смирится с переписыванием огромных файлов несколько раз в секунду, либо сделать индексно-последовательный доступ в том простейшем варианте, что я описал.

Comment: Подумайте, как VARCHAR'ы хранятся в базе данных. То, что в описываете — одно из возможных (и популярных) решений.

Comment: Ну и вы в ответе ничего не говорите ни про какую базу данных (включая Berkeley DB), так что мой комментарий относится к дополнительному файлу с позициями строк + сборщику мусора, о которых вы говорите в ответе.

Comment: @Aldmi, только тут нужно иметь в виду, что прыганье по файлу за значением каждой строки это *очень* дорого (последовательное чтение на порядок быстрее). Т.е. если нужно будет прочесть все (или многие) строки в память, то не следует лазить за ними по в соответствии с индексом (мапом).

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите *добавить* новые строки в середину текстового файла, то вам придётся переписать все 100_000 строк, чтобы добавить только одну строчку в середину (пишите в новый файл новое содержимое, переименовывайте в случае успеха). Если вас это не устраивает, то используйте другой формат, например, работайте с файлом как с базой данных, [используя sqlite библиотеку](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2942370/4279).

> [База не подходит по ТЗ должно быть именно так. Пусть длина строки фиксированная](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566816/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%a1%d0%b8#comment741623_566838)

Если вам нужно только *отредактировать* строки, ***не меняя их длину***, то можно `fseek()/fwrite()` использовать, чтобы отредактировать строку с индексом `line_index`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/** Replace line at *line_index* with *new_line* in the *file*.

    All lines in the *file* are *line_size* size.
    Return non-zero on error (*errno* may be set).
*/
int freplace(size_t line_index, char* new_line, size_t line_size, FILE* file)
{
  return (fseek(file, line_index * line_size, SEEK_SET) ||
          fwrite(new_line, line_size, 1, file) != 1);
}
```

Например, чтобы заменить вторую строчку (индекс `1`) на `abc` в файле `lines.txt`, где все строчки имеют длину `4` (включая перевод строки):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  FILE* file = fopen("lines.txt", "r+b");
  if (file == NULL ||
      freplace(1, "abc\n", 4, file) ||
      fclose(file)) {
    perror("failed to replace the line");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Если `lines.txt`:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

то после запуска программы, содержимое превращается в:

```
aaa
abc
ccc
```