# Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В файле есть определенная строка, ее сначала выводит цикл на экран, всю строку, а потом нужно бы ее изменить, т.е. удалить старое и написать на ней новое, как это делается?

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Замена файле слов, Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/256777/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-python) [Заменить слово в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490305/Заменить-слово-в-файле)

Comment: похожие подходы можно использовать как в вопросе: [Каким образом удалить строчки выборочно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633622/23044) и [How to search and replace text in a file using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17140886/4279)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 15):

Замену можно сделать так:

```
with open ('test.txt', 'r') as f:
  old_data = f.read()

new_data = old_data.replace('что_меняем', 'на_что_меняем')

with open ('test.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(new_data)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно )

Comment: `path = pathlib.Path('test.txt'); path.write_text(path.read_text().replace('old', 'new'))`

Answer (score 5):

Открыть файл на чтение можно либо так

```
file = open('filename.txt', 'r')
firstline = file.readlines()[0].strip()
file.close()
```

Либо так:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    print('first line', f.readlines()[0].strip())
```

Преимущество второго способа в том, что вам не надо закрывать файл вручную. Конструкция `with`сделает это за вас после закрытия её блока.

Перезаписать файл можно же таким образом:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f1, open('filename1.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(f1.read())
```

Но так как вы хотите писать файл с заменой строки, то вам нужно воспользоваться перебором по `readlines()` и либо регулярными выражениями, либо сравнением текущей строки с той, которую вы ищите (если у вас есть искомая строка, конечно) и её заменой.

Грубо говоря, вы можете сделать это как-то так:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f1, open('filename1.txt', 'w') as f2:
    lines = f1.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == 'искомая строка':
            f2.write('новая строка\n')
        else:
            f2.write(line)
```

Также могут помочь функции `startswith()` и `endswith()`, если у вас есть только начало или конец от искомой строки. И **помните про регистр**!

Также можно не перебирать строки, а обратиться к строке по индексу, если вам известно какой у неё номер, и заменить её содержание.

И можно воспользоваться функцией `replace()`, как уже написал автор второго ответа, что сократит количество кода, но **заменит абсолютно все вхождения**. Чтобы этого избежать, при вызове функции **можно указать максимальное число совершаемых замен**: `S.max(sub_in_str, to_change_str, max)`.

Также учитывайте, что `replace()` совершит замену даже если строка частично совпадает. То есть выполнив это:

```
'This is a simple example'.replace('is', 'was')
```

Мы получим `Thwas was a simple example`

Answer (score 5):

Если длина новой строки не совпадает с длиной старой, то придётся переписать весь файл (начиная со строчки, которую вы хотите заменить) даже если вам надо заменить только одну строку в файле ([за редкими исключениями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605130/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0/605146#comment823571_605146)). Связанный вопрос: [Запись текстовой строки по нужному индексу в файл на языке Си?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/566816/23044)

Чтобы в случае ошибки сохранить оригинал или для больших файлов (когда всё содержимое в памяти не помещается), может использоваться *временный файл* куда новое содержимое пишется и в конце в случае успеха он переименовывается в исходное имя файла. Похожий подход использует стандартный модуль `fileinput`: исходный файл переименовывается (чтобы из него читать текущее содержимое), а стандартный вывод перенаправляется в указанный файл (простой print печатает прямо в файл):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
import os

with fileinput.FileInput('файл.txt', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()  # remove trailing (invisible) space
        print('новое' if line == 'старое' else line)  # stdout is redirected to the file
os.unlink(filename + '.bak') # remove the backup on success
```

---

Можно самостоятельно явно временный файл создать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

path = Path('файл.txt')
with path.open() as file, \
     NamedTemporaryFile('w', dir=str(path.parent), delete=False) as output_file: 
     for line in file:
         line = line.rstrip()
         print('новое' if line == 'старое' else line, file=output_file)
Path(output_file.name).replace(path)  # replace the input file on success
```

Отличие в том, что оригинальное содержимое хранится в `.bak` файле в `fileinput` подходе, а в коде с `NamedTemporaryFile` исходный файл заменяется только в случае успеха (в отсутствие исключений).

---

Небольшой файл можно в память целиком загрузить, чтобы получить список строк, изменить нужные и целиком перезаписать этот файл, рискуя потерять данные, если ошибка возникнет при записи (аналогично коду в [@stxdtm ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/654215/23044)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

filename = 'файл.txt'
with open(filename) as file:
    lines = ['новое\n' if line.rstrip() == 'старое' else line for line in file]
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

Подробнее представленные подходы можно [по ссылкам в похожем ответе посмотреть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633665/23044).

---

Если длина новой строки совпадает с длиной старой (в байтах), то можно прямо по месту изменения делать, не переписывая другие части файла, к примеру, используя `mmap` модуль, который позволяет файл рассматривать и как файл (`.readline()`, etc), и как байтовую строку (`.find()`, можно применять регулярные выражения). Связанный вопрос: [Python - How can I change bytes in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28520922/4279).

Answer (score 1):

Название переменных говорит само за себя, также подробные коменты.
Работает на линуксе, возвращяет количество измененных строк.

```
    import os, subprocess
    
    def LineReplacement(File, FindThis, ReplaceByThis):
    
        TemporaryFile = File + '.tmp'            # создаём
        os.system("touch %s" % TemporaryFile)    # временный файл
    
        result = 0 # счетчик измененных строк

        with open(File, 'r') as f1, open(TemporaryFile, 'w') as f2:
            lines = f1.readlines()
    
            for line in lines:
                line = line.strip()
    
                if line == FindThis:
                    f2.write(ReplaceByThis + '\n') # меняем строку
                    result = result + 1 # инкрементирование счетчика измененных строк
                else:
                    f2.write(line + '\n') # оставляем прежнюю
    
        path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), File)
        os.remove(path) # удаляем основной файл
    
        os.system("mv %s %s" % (TemporaryFile, File)) # переименовываем временный в основной
    
    
    File = input("имя файла: ")
    FindThis = input("что менять: ")
    ReplaceByThis = input("на что менять: ")
    
    result = LineReplacement(File, FindThis, ReplaceByThis)

    print("изменено ", result, " строк")
```