# Замена букв по словарю для каждой строчки в файле

Tags: python

Есть txt файл с таким **содержание**м :

```
лев
шут
артур
```

**Нужно** чтобы в этом файле,каждая буква для каждой строки заменилась на ту,что в словаре.
Т.е в итоге чтобы файл был таким :

```
ked
ien
fhneh
```

Вот что я написал :

```
d={'й':'q', 'ц':'w', 'у':'e','к':'r','е':'t','н':'y','г':'u','ш':'i',
'щ':'o','з':'p','х':'[','ъ':']','ф':'a','ы':'s','в':'d','а':'f','п':'g',
'р':'h','о':'j','л':'k','д':'l','ж':';','э':'"','я':'z','ч':'x','с':'c',
'м':'v','и':'b','т':'n','ь':'m','б':',','ю':'.','ё':'`'} # словарь

file3 = open('ассоциации.txt', 'r')
file3read = file3.readlines()
file3.close()
newfile2 = open('ассоциации.txt', 'w')
for line in file3read:
    for character in line:
        if character in d:
            monstro = line.replace(character, d[character])
            newfile2.write(monstro)
```

Но в итоге я получаю такой результат :

```
kев 
лtв 
леd 
iут 
шeт 
шуn 
fртур 
аhтуh 
арnур 
артeр 
аhтуh
```

Где я ошибся ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в цикле, метод replace заменяет только первое вхождение, поэтому, заменяя только одну букву результат замены записывается в файл, после чего все тоже самое повторяется и для следующих букв слова.
Если уж так хочется делать реплейсом, то цикл  можно изменить так(грязь):

```
for line in file3read:
    for character in line:
        if character in d:
            line = line.replace(character, d[character])
    newfile2.write(line)
```

Заметь, что monstro заменено на line для того чтобы результат замены сохранялся и следующая замена производилась в строке с уже произведённой заменой. 
Ещё это все можно заменить генератором списка(а ещё лучше методом созданным специально для таких случаев о котором рассказали в ответе выше):

```
for line in file3read:
    print(''.join([d[ch] for ch in line.rstrip()]), file=newfile2)
```

print используется чтобы не потерялись переносы строк, а их предварительно удаление - чтобы не сломался генератор(хотя тут несколько вариантов решения этой проблемы)

Comment: В последнем варианте нужно учитывать, что символа может не быть в словаре, например делать `d.get(ch, ch)` вместо `d[ch]`

Answer (score 1):

Я бы воспользовался более стандартным методом - [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) + [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate):

```
In [166]: trantab = str.maketrans(''.join(d.keys()), ''.join(d.values()))

In [167]: print(txt)
лев
шут
артур

In [168]: print(txt.translate(trantab))
ktd
ien
fhneh
```

Comment: [`str.translate()` может словарь принимать напрямую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/704261/23044)

Comment: @jfs, да, я в курсе

Comment: не сомневаюсь. Мой комментарий для будущих читателей вашего ответа. Методы не на 100% совместимы. К примеру, `maketrans()` может молча данные испортить, если входной ключ более одного символа содержит (к примеру, из-за нормализации: `'ё'`) и есть значения для замены из более одного символа.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш словарь можно почти без изменений передать в [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). Достаточно номера символов вместо самих символов в качестве ключей использовать:

```
text = text.translate({ord(k): v for k, v in d.items()})
```

Если файл небольшой, то можно целиком его в память прочитать:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('файл.txt')
replacements = {ord(k): v for k, v in d.items()}
path.write_text(path.read_text().translate(replacements))
```

Если файл большой и вы хотите в него же результат замены поместить, то можно использовать временный файл, как это делает [`fileinput` стандартный модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput):

```
import fileinput
import os

filename = 'файл.txt'
with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.translate(replacements), end='')
os.unlink(filename + '.bak')  # remove the backup on success
```

Вывод `print` автоматически перенаправлен в `файл.txt` здесь. `backup='.bak'` говорит, чтобы копия входного файла осталась в `файл.txt.bak` на случай ошибки.

При желании, не сложно самостоятельно временный файл использовать, чтобы не трогать исходный файл в случае ошибки: [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044)