# Как удалить лишние пробелы, оставив по одному между словами, не затрагивая при этом перенос на другую строку?

Tags: python, list

Добрый день.

Помогите, пожалуйста со строками/списками в Питоне.

Есть файл с записанными строками, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Его нужно преобразовать к читабельному формату. 
Я его считываю в Список, Список преобразую в Строку и редактирую её:

```
f = open('./4.txt',"r")
BOOK = f.readlines() 
s = ''.join(BOOK)
f1=open('./3.txt',"a")
s = s.replace('FILIAL_NAME\n','')
s = s.replace('ABON_FIO\n','')
f1.writelines(s)
```

У меня получается следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, как удалить лишние пробелы, оставив по одному между словами, не затрагивая при этом перенос на другую строку? Split() и перенос удаляет, то есть пишется всё сплошной строкой. На каком этапе это лучше сделать (на этапе списка или уже строки) и как?

Хотел запустить цикл до конца строки, если текущий символ и следующий символ равняется " ", то `replace(s[i],'')`, но прочитал, что replace должен быть обязательно чему-то присвоен, и не понял, как это сделать корректно.

`s = re.sub (r'\s+', '',)` Тоже удаляет все пробелы.

В общем, подскажите, как это организовать.

Спасибо.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044)

Answer (score 5):

Я бы сделал так:

```
import re
s = re.sub(" +", " ", s)
```

Ну или так, без импорта re:

```
while "  " in s:
    s= s.replace("  ", " ")
```

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы оставить один пробел:

```
>>> text = "hello     python  world !!"
>>> text.split()
['hello', 'python', 'world', '!!']
>>> new_text = ' '.join(text.split())
print(new_text)
'hello python world !!'
```

Comment: Знак переноса строки `\n` тоже удалится, это не подходит, к сожалению.

Comment: @nick_gabpe, так читайте не весь файл целиком, а построчно, в каждой отдельной строке удаляя лишние пробелы.

Comment: @insolor просто ТС просил без удаления `\n`. Мне такое решение пришло в голову первым.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующий код, должен получиться список с элементами вида `[номер Филиал номер Ф И О]`. Приложили бы данные текстом, а не картинкой - я бы проверил.

```
f = open('./4.txt',"r")
# Получим строки с данными (начинаются с числа)
result = []
for line in f:
    line = line.split()
    if line[0].isdigit():
        result.append(line)
# В случае если филиал и имена идут чередуясь
end_result = []
for i in range(0, len(result), 2):
    end_result.append(result[i] + result[i+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    text = '\n'.join(' '.join(line.split()) for line in f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while s.find('  ') != -1:
    s = s.replace('  ', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = """
hello     python  world !!
hello     python  world   !!
hello   python    world !!
"""
text
'\nhello     python  world !!\nhello     python  world   !!\nhello   python    world !!\n'

print(' '.join([ t for t in  text.split(' ') if t ]))

hello python world !!
hello python world !!
hello python world !!
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s = '   здесь  много     лишних пробелов  '.strip() 
while "  " in s:
    s= s.replace("  ", " ") 
print(s)
```