# Замена строк в файле Python

Tags: python

Друзья, необходимо прочитать файл и заменить одно целое число на другое на единицу больше и записать вместо первого в файл. Может кто-то подсказать как это реализовать в Python.

```
def check():
with open('users.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    f.close()
with open('progress.txt', 'r') as k:
    while True:
        global uroka_in
        lines = k.readline()
        if line == lines.rstrip():
            uroka_in = int(k.readline().rstrip())
            urokb_in = uroka_in + 1
            print(urokb_in)
            uroka_str = str(uroka_in)
            urokb_str = str(urokb_in)
            lines.replace(uroka_str, urokb_str)
            k.close()
            break
        if not lines:
            k.close()
            urokb_in = 1
            with open('progress.txt', 'a') as j:
                j.write(line)
                j.write('\n')
                j.write(str(urokb_in))
                j.write('\n')
                j.close()
                print(urokb_in)
                break
```

Пример записи в progress.txt:

```
username1
1
username2
1
```

Хочу эти единички менять на +1 каждый раз когда в users.txt попадает аналогичный username

Comment: приведите код - что у вас не получается.
просто в три строчки.
- открываем файл на чтение
- открываем (другой) файл на запись
- читаем строку
- делаем +1
- записываем в файл
- удаляем старый файл
- переименовываем новый файл
- меняем данные

Comment: нельзя ли без создания нового файла

Comment: можно, но перезапись в "тот же" файл технически сложнее.
все равно нужно перезаписать все до конца файла.
похоже - пора перейти к базам данных :-)
SQLite3 - встроена в язык

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044)

Comment: если файл маленький, то можно в json формате хранить данные json легко загрузить, при изменении вы работаете со привычными списками, словарями, легко записать назад на диск. В зависимости от конкретных операций, может больше смысла sqlite базу записать как @Vasyl Kolomiets предложил.