# Добавить записи в DBF python

Tags: python, dbf

я использую библиотеку dbfpy. Записи могу добавить я так понял, только в конец, также при удалении, записи не удаляются физически, а только помечаются удаленными.
Еще проблема, если у меня в таблице уже идет упорядоченный список записей. пример. и мне надо вставить запись в середину, между ними. Не получиться, все равно допишет записи в конец. Перезаписать - получается, с этим проблем нет.

```
111111
222222   < 232332  хочу сюда вставить, не перезаписать, а именно вставить
333333
444444
```

Вот и вопрос, как добавить запись в середину и как удалить запись полностью?

Comment: в сторону: интересно, где сейчас используется формат, созданный для 8-битовых машин с CP/M (ещё до DOS)?¶ Вероятно для такого древнего формата нет опции записи в середину файла, по той же причине что и для других обычных файлов: [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044) То есть возможное решение (если формат не поддерживает напрямую запись): читайте из старого файла в новый, дойдя до нужно строчки добавьте новую строчку, продолжайте из старого копировать, в конце переименуйте файл.

Comment: 1с, на самом деле оптимальный формат, хорош тем что не надо ничего ставить, серверов и тд, я тоже за оптимизацию) но руководству по барабану. Да именно так и делаю, но почему то так долго работает... чтение 350 тыщ строк и запись в новый файл, занимает 60 секунд... i3 проц... файл то всего 10 мб, странно, это изза библиотеки?

Comment: сравните с тем как sqlite с той же задачей справится.