# Замена неправильных имён функций в файлах с Питон 2 кодом

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Существуют `N` кол-во файлов, где необходимо найти названия функций и заменить их на формат по pep8 в этих же файлах.
Как это можно проделать ?
Пока имеется след.: я маплю все эти «неправильные» имена функций и превращаю их в «правильные». Остался вопрос как эти старые имена заменить на новые ?

```
import glob, os, re

def convert(name):
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dir = 'D:\..\..\..'
    os.chdir(dir)
    def_list = []
    for file in glob.glob("*.py"):
        f = open(file)
        for line in f:
            wostrip = line.lstrip()
            if wostrip.startswith('def'):
                method_name = wostrip[wostrip.find(' ') + 1:wostrip.find('(')]
                if method_name != convert(method_name):
                    def_list.append((method_name, convert(method_name)))
        end_list = list(set(def_list))
        end_list.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])
    for def_ in end_list:
        old_name = def_[0] # старые имена
        new_name = def_[1] # новые имена
```

Comment: вы хотите просто одну строку на другую заменить, рассматривая файл как простой текст (к примеру с помощью регулярного выражения) или вы хотите как исходный код (какой язык?) рассматривать (только имена функций рассматривать)? (парсер языка нужен)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044)

Comment: Python 2.7.x У меня есть некоторые файлы, где названия функции обозваны не по pep8. Я пока написал только вывод каждой такой функции из этих файлов (`def testTestTest()` -> `def test_test_test()` ). Но проблема в том, что я не могу найти способ заменить каждое старое название функции на новое. В том примере, что вы скинули - не совсем то. Там идёт конкретная замена и только в определённом файле.

Comment: если вы не знаете как можно обобщить пример, к примеру, чтобы замена не в одном жёстко прошитом файле была, а в файлах, указанных в командной строке, то просто задайте отдельный вопрос: "есть пример X, который делает Y, как его изменить, чтобы он делал Z"

Comment: отредактировал свой вопрос, добавил больше описаний и текущее состояние

Comment: если всё что вы хотите это привести в соответствие с pep-8, то есть специализированные инструменты типа autopep8. Можно также автоматически отформатировать код в соответствии с желаемыми настройками, используя yapf [и другие](https://github.com/pycqa/pycodestyle/wiki/RelatedTools). Вы можете попробовать настроить ваше IDE, чтобы при сохранении файлы автоматически форматировались.

Answer (score 4):

Есть [2to3 утилита](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html), которая меняет Питон 2 код в Питон 3 код. Можно `lib2to3` библиотеку использовать, чтобы произвольные изменения в Питон-код вносить.
К примеру, чтобы поменять заданные имена, используя словарь замен, [можно свой fixer определить](http://python3porting.com/fixers.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from lib2to3.fixer_base import BaseFix
from lib2to3.pgen2 import token

class FixRename(BaseFix):

    _accept_type = token.NAME

    def __init__(self, options, log, *, substitutions=None, **kwargs):
        self.__substitutions = substitutions
        super().__init__(options, log, **kwargs)

    def match(self, node):
        return node.value in self.__substitutions

    def transform(self, node, results):
        node.value = self.__substitutions[node.value]
        node.changed()
```

Запустить инструмент, подставив свой фикс, можно переопределив `get_fixers()` метод:

```
"""Usage: rename-functions [--write] [<dir-or-file>...]"""
import os
import sys
from lib2to3.main import StdoutRefactoringTool

def main():
    substitutions = {'greet': 'say_hello'}  # compute your substitutions here

    class RefactoringTool(StdoutRefactoringTool):
        def get_fixers(self):
            return [FixRename(self.options, self.fixer_log,
                              substitutions=substitutions)], []

    try:
        sys.argv.remove('--write')
    except ValueError:
        do_write = False
    else:
        do_write = True

    t = RefactoringTool([], options={}, explicit=None, nobackups=None,
                        show_diffs=not do_write)
    t.refactor(sys.argv[1:] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else [os.curdir],
               write=do_write)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

К примеру, если есть `example.py`:

```
def greet(name):
    print "Hello, {0}!".format(name)
print "What's your name?"
name = raw_input()
greet(name)
```

То команда `rename-functions example.py` вернёт diff:

```
--- example.py  (original)
+++ example.py  (refactored)
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-def greet(name):
+def say_hello(name):
     print "Hello, {0}!".format(name)
 print "What's your name?"
 name = raw_input()
-greet(name)
+say_hello(name)
```

Передав `--write` опцию, можно по месту входные файлы изменить.

В общем случае [узлы для замены, можно с помощью шаблонов искать](http://python3porting.com/fixers.html#finding-the-nodes-with-patterns).

Answer (score 0):

получается у вас есть метод, скажем, get_method_names_for_replacement, возвращающий маппинг старое имя - новое имя
что-то вроде {'testTestTest': 'test_test_test',}
тогда можно бежать во всем файлам и обрабатывать их в цикле.
ниже примерный код без учёта нюансов (не учитывается, что имя метода может быть подстрокой другого метода, не учитывается, что помимо объявления методов бывают ещё и вызовы этих методов, в том числе из других классов/файлов, и т.п.). Но под нюансы должно быть несложно адаптировать...
(если я правильно понял вопрос, конечно)

```
filelist = ['filename01', 'filename02']
for filename in filelist:
    with open (filename, 'r') as f:
        old_data = f.read()
    names_map = get_method_names_for_replacement(old_data)
    new_data = old_data
    for old_name in names_map:
        new_data = new_data.replace(old_name, names_map[old_name])
    with open (filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(new_data)
```