# Как изменить содержимое .py файлов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

> Имеется файл file.py, его содержимое вы найдёте ниже:
>
> ```
> def as():
>     print("Hello")
> def das():
>     print("World!")
> as()
> ```
>
> Требуется заменить строку 'as()' на 'das()'.

Я пробовал осуществить данное действие следующим кодом, но ничего не вышло, file.py не изменился.

```
file = open('file.py', 'r+')
for i in range(1, 5):
    file.readline()
file.write('das()')
file.close()
```

Как я должен изменить код #2, чтобы file.py изменился нужным мне образом?

Comment: Зачем? Это какое-то тестовое задание?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+replace+string+in+a+text+file&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ,  нет, я сам создаю себе проблемы. Я имею приложение commander, которое должно запускать мини-приложения. Для удобства я создаю приложение AddCom, которое должно импортировать приложения в launchcom(Этот модуль должен запускать мини-приложения.).

Comment: Для подобных целей разумнее не изменять текст файлов, а импортировать и запускать нужные функции на лету.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev , а всё-таки вариант с изменением .ру файлов осуществим?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Замена неправильных имён функций в файлах с Питон 2 кодом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/788773/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, `as` - ключевое слово, его нельзя использовать в качестве имени функции. Поэтому я поменяю названия функций на *пайтонические* `spam` и `eggs`.

```
def spam():
    print("Hello")


def eggs():
    print("World!")


spam()
```

Во-вторых, как я уже писал, изменять текст исходного файла - это костыльное решение задачи, но всё же возможное:

```
lines = None
with open('file.py') as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()

lines[-1] = 'eggs()'

with open('file.py', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(''.join(lines))
```

Разумнее модифицировать не текст, а [абстрактное синтаксическое дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE):

```
import ast

class CallChanger(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Call(self, node):
        if node.func.id == 'spam':
            node.func.id = 'eggs'
        return node


with open('file.py') as fh:
    tree = ast.parse(fh.read())
    CallChanger().visit(tree)
    code = compile(tree, filename='file.py', mode='exec')
    exec(code)
```

Но и это оверкилл для такого динамического языка, как Python. Ведь можно просто импортировать и вызвать что угодно в рантайме:

```
module_name = 'file'
func_name = 'eggs'

m = __import__(module_name)
f = getattr(m, func_name)
f()
```