# Перезаписать текстовый файл в числовой, соответствующий поряковому номеру в алфавите

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, текст

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перезаписать текст из файла в новый, где новый текст будет содержать позицию (нумерацию) из алфавита. Например, для текстового файла с содержанием "ABC" нужно записать новый файл с контентом "123"(где А=1, В=2 - порядковый номер в английском алфавите). Заранее благодарю.

Comment: @VladSpirin Это и есть он, только на русском языке.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь: [Тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), далее [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Алгоритм:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

text = 'HelloWorld'

for c in text.upper():
    pos = ascii_uppercase.index(c) + 1
    positions.append(pos)

print(positions)  # [8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4]
```

---

Реализация (с удалением не латинских букв):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import re

# Открытие файла для считывания из него
with open('input.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    
    # Удаление из строки всех символов, не входящих в диапазон латинских букв
    text = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]+', '', text)

# Запись результата в файл
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for c in text.upper():
        pos = ascii_uppercase.index(c) + 1
        f.write(str(pos))
```

Реализация (с сохранением не латинских букв):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

# Открытие файла для считывания из него
with open('input.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

# Запись результата в файл
with open('out.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for i in text:
        c = i.upper()

        if c in ascii_uppercase:
            pos = ascii_uppercase.index(c) + 1
            f.write(str(pos))

        else:
            f.write(i)
```

---

**@jfs** предложил интересный способ замены латинских букв их порядком через регулярку (с сохранением исходного текста):

```
import re

# Открытие файла для считывания из него
with open('input.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

    # Замена латинских букв на их порядок в алфавите
    text = re.sub(r'[A-Za-z]', lambda m: str(ord(m.group().upper())-ord('A') + 1), text)

    # Запись результата в файл
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
        out.write(text)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/797546/201445

Comment: предыдущий ответ удалил :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное за столь быструю реакцию. Повторила ваш алгоритм, но у меня возникает ошибка:                                        pos = string.ascii_uppercase.index(c) + 1
ValueError: substring not found

Comment: в файле могут быть не только английские буквы. `re.sub(r'[A-Za-z]', lambda m: str(ord(m.group().upper())-ord('A') + 1), text)`

Comment: jfs, конечно могут быть не только английские буквы, но и пунктуация, пробелы и т.п. ,но в вопросе об этом не слова, поэтому не стал усложнять алгоритм. @u_lialia, достаточно будет перед обработкой исключить все не английские буквы?

Comment: @jfs, а почему бы просто не так сделать: `re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]+', '', 'aBc123 ?,АВГд')`?

Comment: 1- `ValueError` с вами не согласно о том какой ввод должен быть 2- ваш re.sub пытается что-то удалить (не вижу никакого отношения к задаче). Выражение, которое я привёл берёт text строку и заменяет все английские буквы на порядковый номер в алфавите. (то что в вопросе спрашивается)

Comment: понятно, спасибо за объяснение, 1) интересно, как у вас `ValueError` вышел... 2) интересное применение регулярки :)

Comment: Ребят, все работает, огромное спасибо! Я новичок в Python, пыталась реализовать данную задачу около трех дней, и сегодня решила зарегаться на данном сайте. Я шокирована тем, насколько быстро пришел ответ. ЗдОрово!

Comment: @u_lialia, и помните: ["Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :D

Answer (score 1):

```
import string

dt = {ord(s): str(string.ascii_lowercase.index(s.lower()) + 1) for s in string.ascii_letters}

with open('in.txt') as f1, open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(str.translate(f1.read(), dt))
```