# Изменить число в одном файле если оно равно числу в другом файле

Tags: python

У меня имеются два файла:

`1.txt`

```
0.12
0.32
0.44
0.56
0.60
```

`2.txt`

```
0.13
0.44
0.60
```

Нужно изменить файл `1.txt` в следующее:

```
0.12
0.32
0.439
0.56
0.599
```

где 0.599 может иметь сколько угодно чисел после запятой. Основная задача, чтобы оно было меньше 0.60.

Мой код:

```
with open('1.txt') as phone_file, \
     open('2.txt') as syl_file:

    for line_p in phone_file:
        for line_s in syl_file:
            if line_p == line_s:
                line_p = line_s-0.001

            print(line_p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = []    # Список выходных строк

with open('1.txt') as phone_file, \
     open('2.txt') as syl_file:

    # Вытаскиваем строки из текстовых файлов, 
    # обрезая перевод строки и пробелы
    p_lines = [line.strip() for line in phone_file]  
    s_lines = [line.strip() for line in syl_file]    

    for line_p in p_lines:
        new_p = float(line_p)-0.001 if line_p in s_lines else float(line_p)
        output.append(str(new_p))

# Теперь открываем файл только для записи
with open('1.txt', 'w') as phone_file:
    for line in output:
        # И вставляем в него получившиеся числа
        phone_file.write(str(line) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы по месту изменения делать, можно [`fileinput` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) использовать (`print` печатает в файл, см. [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from fileinput import FileInput
from math import inf

with FileInput('numbers.txt', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as numbers_file, \
     open('bins.txt') as bins_file:
    bins = map(float, bins_file)
    b = next(bins)
    # assume sorted and all numbers are within bins range
    for x in map(float, numbers_file):
        while x > b:
            b = next(bins)
        if x == b:
            x = nextafter(x, -inf) # previous
        print(x)
```

[Результат](https://repl.it/@zed1/replace-with-smaller):

```
0.12
0.32
0.43999999999999995
0.56
0.5999999999999999
```

Здесь [`nextafter()` функция](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter) используется, чтобы найти float, которое меньше заданного. На CPython, можно из Си библиотеки её повзаимствовать:

```
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)
nextafter = libc.nextafter
nextafter.restype = ctypes.c_double
nextafter.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double]
```

чтобы получить результат как в вопросе, вы можете определить: `nextafter = lambda x, y: x - .001`

Answer (score 1):

С использованием Pandas модуля:

```
import pandas as pd

# read up files into Pandas.Series variables   
s1 = pd.read_csv(r'1.txt', header=None, squeeze=True)
s2 = pd.read_csv(r'2.txt', header=None, squeeze=True)

delta = 1e-6

# subtract [delta] from matchig elements
s1.loc[s1.isin(s2)] -= delta

# overwrite [1.txt] with modified data
s1.to_csv(r'1.txt', header=None, index=False)
```

Содержимое обновленного файла:

```
In [14]: print(open(r'1.txt').read())
0.12
0.32
0.43999900000000003
0.56
0.599999
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно [`numpy.isin(a, b)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy.isin) использовать, чтобы узнать какие элементы из `a` равны элементам из `b` (какие значения нужно уменьшить в текущей задаче):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt('numbers.txt')
bins = np.loadtxt('bins.txt')

a[np.isin(a, bins)] -= .001

np.savetxt('output.txt', a, '%g')
```

Вывод:

```
0.12
0.32
0.439
0.56
0.599
```

Вариант, который использует тот факт, что элементы отсортированы, вызывая [`numpy.searchsorted()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt('numbers.txt')
bins = np.loadtxt('bins.txt')

ind = np.searchsorted(a, bins)
eq = a[ind]
eq[eq == bins] -= .001
a[ind] = eq

np.savetxt('output.txt', a, '%g')
```

Тот же результат.