# Добавление вводимой информации в выбранную строку

Tags: python

суть моего обращения в следующем.
Написал данный код, который работал и выводил строку под нужным номером, но после определённой итерации стал выдавать ошибку "list index out of range" с жалобой на строку
"f = f.readlines()[N-1]"
(Учитывая, что в N вводится число от 1 до 5 соответствующие номеру строки в файле)

А так же хотел попросить подсказать, как сделать, чтобы информация записывалась следом в нужную строку, а не печаталась на новой и как включить готовую строку в существующий изначальный файл.(В данном случае, чтобы в строку добавился новый третий город, который вводит пользователь)

Заранее большое спасибо за помощь.

```
f = open('план.txt', 'r', encoding= 'utf-8')
print("Исходный список: "+'\n'+ "".join(f))
N = int(input("Введите номер строки: "))
g = str(input("Введите новый город: "))
f = f.readlines()[N-1]
f = f +', '+ g
print(f)
```

Текст исходного файла:

```
1;"Магнит";магазин;10000000;Москва, Волгоград
2;"Лента";магазин;80000000;Санкт-Петербург, Самара
3;"Лукойль";АЗС;10000000;Сочи, Анапа
4;"Татнефть";АЗС;90000000;Москва, Санкт-Петербург
5;"Пятерочка";магазин;80000000;Сочи, Ростов-на-Дону
```

Comment: Файл хорошо бы закрывать. Или открывать через `with`. А какой номер строки вы вводили, когда ошибка выходила? Покажите ввод и ошибку, иначе это беспредметный разговор.

Comment: Введите номер строки: 3

Введите новый город: Москва
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "K:\план\untitled1.py", line 5, in <module>
    f = f.readlines()[N-1]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: А вообще ошибку выводит при вводе любого числа, даже в рамках от 1 до 5

Comment: А напечатайте `print(f.readlines())`, посмотрим, что там, может переводы строки не подхватились, например?

Comment: Написал принт перед строчкой на которую жалуется, выводит пустой список

Comment: А код точно тот, который вы показали? Я полагаю, что вы один раз открываете файл, а потом в цикле делаете всё остальное. Файл читается один раз, а потом уже не читается, потому что указатель файла достиг конца файла. Либо делайте `f.seek(0)` перед `f.readlines()`, либо открывайте файл заново каждую итерацию цикла.

Comment: Код именно тот, который прикрепил. Специально создал новый файл, где находится только этот код.

Comment: написал "f.seek(0)", теперь в принте выводится список со строками, но ошибка та же. Элементов в списке 5.

Comment: Введите номер строки: 4

Введите новый город: Москва
['1;"Магнит";магазин;10000000;Москва, Волгоград\n', '2;"Лента";магазин;80000000;Санкт-Петербург, Самара\n', '3;"Лукойль";АЗС;10000000;Сочи, Анапа\n', '4;"Татнефть";АЗС;90000000;Москва, Санкт-Петербург\n', '5;"Пятерочка";магазин;80000000;Сочи, Ростав-на-Дону\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "K:\план\untitled1.py", line 7, in <module>
    f = f.readlines()[N-1]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Но думаю, что дальше сам разберусь. Спасибо большое за ответы

Comment: Хотел спросить, как эту строку (уже редактированную, с добавленным городом) внести в исходный файл, чтобы она заменила предыдущую её версию (с двумя городами)

Comment: @colden Похожий вопрос уже задавали [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183). Я уверен что там вы найдёте ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Посмотрел, но для своего случая не смог найти. Мне нужно, чтобы он нашёл исходную строку с которой мы работали и заменил её на ту, которая получилась после всех манипуляций.
Если это поможет, то старая строка сохранена в переменную k, а новая строка в переменной f. Нужно в файле их заменить. Как это можно сделать?